# React/Router not rendering Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem  with react router not rendering all my pages/components. So when i Click on the Page 1 it renders the content inside of it but when I click on the page 2 or 3 it doesnt render it. It only renders the first Component/Page 1. I would like some help if possible.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <NavBar/>
    <Router>
    <Switch>
     
     <Route exact path='/Page1' component={Page1}/>
        <Page1/>
     <Route exact  path='/Page2' component={Page2}/>
        <Page2/>
     <Route exact path='/Page3' component={Page3}/>
        <Page3/>
      <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>

     </Switch>
     </Router>
     
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;




function NavBar(props) {
    return (
        <Router>
        <div className="nav">
             <div className="nav1">
            <Link to='/'> 
             Home
            </Link>

            <Link to='/page1'> 
             Page 1
            </Link>

            <Link to='/page2'> 
              Page2
            </Link>
      
            <Link to='/page3'> 
              Page3
            </Link>
         </div>
          </div>
          </Router>

        )
}

export default NavBar
```

Comment: Not sure if React router cares, but the cases of your paths don't match, `/Page2 !== /page2`.  Check if that is the issue.

Comment: That is not the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things to discuss.  Let's break each one out individually:

### Route Paths are Not Case Sensitive

The route paths are not case sensitive as I thought initially and as others through the issue was, but I would suggest you keep them exactly the same for sanity and to keep fellow devs from having to wonder

### NavBar Should Not Have Its Own Router

Your `Router` should wrap both your navbar and the routes.  Right now they each have unique routers

React Router works entirely off of [`React.Context`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).  Your hierarchy right now is:

```
└── App
    ├── NavBar
    │   └── Router (Router A)
    └── Router (Router B)
```

All the React Router HoC (`<Link/>`, `<Route/>`, etc) call `useContext()` under the hood in order to get the nearest context created by `<Router/>`.  Since `<NavBar/>` has its own `Router`, that's the one it will affect.  You need it to be:

```
.
└── App
    └── Router (Only Router)
        └── NavBar
```

That way the `<Link/>`s in `NavBar` will affect the ***only and correct*** router `Context`.

### Improper Switch Children

A `<Switch/>` should *only* have `Route` or `Redirect` as children, you have plain components as children which may also be contributing to the issue

From [`<Switch>#children: node`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch/children-node)

> All children of a `<Switch>` should be `<Route>` or `<Redirect>`
> elements. Only the first child to match the current location will be
> rendered.

### Working Example

Putting all that together, we can take a look at the following example:

```js
const {render} = ReactDOM;
const {BrowserRouter: Router, Switch, Link, Route} = ReactRouterDOM;

const BadNavBar = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>Bad Nav Bar</h2>
    <p>This Nav Bar will affect its own personal Router</p>
    <Router> {/* Router A */}
      {/*
        * These Links will only change the path of Router A
        * because that is the context they will receive internally
        * when their components call for useHistory (this is hidden from you)
        */}
      <Link to="/">Home</Link>
      <Link to="/page1">Page 1</Link>
      <Link to="/page2">Page 2</Link>
    </Router>
  </div>
);

const GoodNavBar = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>Good Nav Bar</h2>
    <p>This Nav Bar will affect the "right" Router because that's the one Context it will use</p>
    <div>
      {/*
        * These Links will change the path of the nearest Router
        * in the component hierarchy (or throw an error if there is
        * no Router in the hierarchy)
        */}
      <Link to="/">Home</Link>
      <Link to="/page1">Page 1</Link>
      <Link to="/page2">Page 2</Link>
    </div>
  </div>
);

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <BadNavBar />
    <Router> {/* Router B */}
      <GoodNavBar />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">I'm Home</Route>
        <Route exact path="/page1">I'm Page 1</Route>
        <Route exact path="/page2">I'm Page 2</Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </div>
);

render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom@5.2.0/umd/react-router-dom.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

### Working Example Using Your Code

Based on the above example, you want the following:

```js
const {render} = ReactDOM;
const {BrowserRouter: Router, Switch, Link, Route} = ReactRouterDOM;

const Home = () => <div>Home</div>;
const Page1 = () => <div>Page 1</div>;
const Page2 = () => <div>Page 2</div>;
const Page3 = () => <div>Page 3</div>;

function NavBar(props) {
  // Remove the Router here
  return (
    <div className="nav">
      <div className="nav1">
        <Link to='/'> 
          Home
        </Link>
        <Link to='/page1'> 
          Page 1
        </Link>
        <Link to='/page2'> 
          Page2
        </Link>
        <Link to='/page3'> 
          Page3
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

// export default NavBar  

function App() {
  // Move NavBar into the Router
  // Remove the explicit pages since that's what the Routes are for
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <NavBar/>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/Page1' component={Page1}/>
          {/*<Page1/>*/}
          <Route exact path='/Page2' component={Page2}/>
          {/*<Page2/>*/}
          <Route exact path='/Page3' component={Page3}/>
          {/*<Page3/>*/}
          <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

// export default App;

render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom@5.2.0/umd/react-router-dom.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: If I wrap it inside of the router nothing renders not even a Page1

Comment: @tekila12 No, I'm possitive this is the issue.  Please check the code in my example.  Your NavBar should not have a `<Router/>` of its own.  There should only be 1 `<Router/>` and the `<NavBar/>` should be inside of it.

Comment: if I put your GoodNavBar LInks without a Router error pops up "You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>"

Comment: @tekila12 Correct, that's why you put it into the Router.  How would it affect the router if it can't reach it?  This whole mechanism is based on `React.Context`s.  If the thing that uses the router isn't in a component chain with a Router as a parent, it can't tell the Router context what to do and throws an error.

Comment: It was sadly my mistake. Thank you for right answer

Answer (score 1):

Your Links does not point to the same routes, you've made a typo, change your to="/page1" to *to='/Page1'*

Comment: This did not help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a few errors here:

1. your path's are not the same as Chandelier pointed out
2. your route declarations are incorrect:

more on point 2:

You have a route declared, and you pass it a component prop, but you also render the actual page below it; this is incorrect:

```
<Route exact path='/Page1' component={Page1}/>
  <Page1/>
```

I'm not sure which version of react router you're using, but I think you have to pick 1 approach; either pass a component prop, or render the actual contents as a child of the Route component:

```
<Route exact path='/page1' component={Page1}/>
```

OR

```
<Route exact path='/page1'>
  <Page1 />
</Route>
```

Comment: Still the same story.

Comment: have you checked the docs and attempted to replicate their example first? https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start

Comment: But when I switch it manually. When I manually write it like this " locahost/Page2" or 3 it works it shows the content but when I click on it it doesnt.

Comment: see this example: https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadabdul3/d9wk352v/8/

Answer (score 0):

you've made a typo: /page1 !== /Page1

declare a constant variable for consistency. For example:

```
const route = "/home";
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <NavBar/>
    <Router>
    <Switch>
       <Route exact path={route} component={Page1}/>
     </Switch>
     </Router>
     
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;




function NavBar(props) {
    return (
        <Router>
        <div className="nav">
             <div className="nav1">
            <Link to={route}> 
             Page 1
            </Link>
         </div>
          </div>
          </Router>

        )
}

export default NavBar
```